# Forwarding a response email: Is it ok to correct your original message?

Tags: email, email-etiquette

I rushed an email that my boss asked me to carbon copy him into and I accidentally carbon copied to
`his name <confluence url>`.
I think it might have auto completed as most of my emails from him were from him updating confluence?

I noticed my mistake and forwarded the reply I got on to him but removed the cc to confluence from my original email.

This was in outlook from a Mac.

For future reference was this the right move or if emails are logged? will this look bad.

Comment: It's not likely anyone is going to care, but if he asks "Why didn't you initially CC me", you're going to be forced to either carry on with a lie saying you forgot, or admit you made an error and decided to try to clean it up so he wouldn't notice. No point stressing about it, cause it's really not likely to come up.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You sent to the wrong address originally then corrected the thread, I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 5):

> For future reference was this the right move or if emails are logged? will this look bad.

In the future, own up to and apologize for your mistakes instead of trying to cover them up.  It almost always looks worse if you are caught trying to cover up a mistake as opposed to simply making a mistake.

Comment: Yep, mistakes can be forgiven, attempts to bury such, rarely so.

Answer (score 2):

Misclicks happen all the time.  You just misclicked the Confluence automailer as your boss since they had the same name.  Just explain it like that, it shouldn't be a big deal.